# getting the size of values.xml in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, random

I'm doing a task in my android class, and in my values folder, I created a file called "values.xml" and in it I placed some random strings:

```
<string name="name1">John</string>
<string name="name2">Jane</string>
<string name="name3">Andre</string>
```

in my java file, I would like to get a random string, but I want this to be based on the size of the values.xml

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomString = getResources().getString(random.nextInt(3));
textView.setText(randomString);
```

this creates and fetches a random string, but instead of

```
random.nextInt(3);
```

I want it to fetch values.xml.size(); or something similar.
Is there a smart way to do this? I've searched everywhere!

Comment: you can try using <string-array> and can get size of array data at runtime getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_array).length;

Comment: Arun, you have a good answer. Could you please post it as an answer instead of a comment, and also point out why doing `getString()` with random integers is not doing what Ola expects?

Comment: @ArunKumar, your comment shows very correct answer. Should be upvoted frequently, and selected as correct. Please make an answer with a short sample, if you can.

Comment: posted comment as answer now :-) ...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get all the strings in the XML value file:

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
//fields.length would be the count of all the string in your xml file
int rand = random.nextInt(fields.length)
String randomText = getResources().getString(fields[rand].getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  for set of elements :

```
<string-array name="name_array">
        <item>John</item>
        <item>Jane</item>
        <item>Andre</item>
    </string-array>
```

And you can get size of array at runtime using below code:

```
int size = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data_array).length;
```